# Asp.net Handling duplicate key exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to handle duplicate key exception in detailsview, and my code under iteminserted is:

```
if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("duplicate key")
    {
        Response.Write("Student already registered!");
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
```

The code is running correctly when there is duplicate key, but in normal situation (no duplicate key) it gives following error:

‫**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is null before running the If statement.

```
if (e.Exception.Message != null){
      if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("duplicate key")
       {
         Response.Write("Student already registered!");
         e.ExceptionHandled = true;
       }   
 }
```